# How to read Read .xls file having html table like data in Stringbuffer?

Tags: java, io, jxl

I am using **StringBuffer** to write data into xls file(where inside StringBuffer I am using **HTML table** code),and while trying to read the same xls file I am unable to read,Could you please help on this.**Using jxl-1.0 jar**--
**Note** : I am able to read normal xls file with my code (but unable to read my generated xls file) 
**For generating xls file**

```
package com.java;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    public class WriteXlsFile {
            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
            {
                StringBuffer sbf = new StringBuffer();
                sbf.append("<table>");
                sbf.append("<tr>");
                sbf.append("<th>Firstname</th>");
                sbf.append("<th>Lastname</th>");
                sbf.append("<th>Age</th>");
                sbf.append("</tr>");
                sbf.append("<tr>");
                sbf.append("<td>Jill</td>");
                sbf.append("<td>Smith</td>");
                sbf.append("<td>50</td>");
                sbf.append("</tr>");
                sbf.append("<tr>");
                sbf.append("<td>Eve</td>");
                sbf.append("<td>Jackson</td>");
                sbf.append("<td>94</td>");
                sbf.append("</tr>");
                sbf.append("</table>");          
                BufferedWriter bwr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("d:/demo.xls")));
                bwr.write(sbf.toString());
                bwr.flush();
                bwr.close();
                System.out.println("Content of StringBuffer written to File.");
            }
    }
```

Reading Xls file

```
package com.java;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
public class ReadXls {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ReadXls reading = new ReadXls();
        String filePath = "D:/demo.xls";
        String sheetName = "demo";
        List al = null;
        al = reading.readExcelFile(filePath,sheetName);
        System.out.println("ReadXls.main()  al  ::: "+al);
    }
    public List readExcelFile(String filePath, String sheetName)  
    {
        FileInputStream fs = null;
        try {
            File f = new File(filePath);
            fs = new FileInputStream(f);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Workbook wb = null;
        try {
            wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);
        } catch (BiffException | IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
        Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(sheetName);
        int totalNoOfRows = sh.getRows();
        int totalNoOfCols = sh.getColumns();
        List finalData = new ArrayList();
        for (int row = 0; row < totalNoOfRows; row++) 
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < totalNoOfCols; col++) 
            {               
                String eachColCell = sh.getCell(col, row).getContents();            
                finalData.add(sh.getCell(col, row).getContents());          
            }
        }
        return finalData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this so simple... `XLS` is not `HTML`, the Excell program has this functionality, but it isn't like that... it parses the table from html and converts it to an actual xls sheet, you can't just save regular `HTML` file under the `xls` extension and open it as `XLS` file - it will not convert magically.
You need to find some library that can do that, eg. https://github.com/alanhay/html-exporter

Comment: Is there any option to read the generated .xls file data and save in collection object like ArrayList.

Comment: any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

You are not writing a file in the XLS format, but an HTML file that is understood by Excel as tabular data. When reading that file, JXL expects a file in the XLS format.

You need to use the [write API](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/write/package-summary.html) of XLS, but I don't know if that API is available in version 1.0. Alternatively (if you are not tied to JXL in your project), you can use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/), which supports a broader range of features.

Comment: I am not tied to JXL in my project, Can I read my generated .xls file using Apache POI. If yes, How can I achieve this(I mean any Jar name ? or and any sample program because I am new to this). But I want to read my generated xls file and save it in any collection object.

Comment: any idea on how to achieve?